# Last time. Is await working with threads?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, task, async-await

I saw some similar questions before, just want to clarify it.

In [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), it is said **"There is no thread"** for async calls.

However, [in another one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx), it is said

> Here, however, we’re running the callback to update the Text of
>   textBox1on some arbitrary thread, wherever the Task Parallel Library
>   (TPL) implementation of ContinueWith happened to put it.

Also, in some cases, when i was calling ContinueWith in my project, i also got "cross-thread access exception.

So, who is right?

ANSWER: thanks to i3arnon. After reading first article more carefully, i found this place

> So, we see that there was no thread while the request was in flight.
>   When the request completed, various threads were “borrowed” or had
>   work briefly queued to them. This work is usually on the order of a
>   millisecond or so (e.g., the APC running on the thread pool) down to a
>   microsecond or so (e.g., the ISR). But there is no thread that was
>   blocked, just waiting for that request to complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both are. When you have code running on your CPU there's always a thread running it. The question is what happens when you don't have code to run, for example when you are waiting for an IO operation to complete.

If you use `async await` where you should there would be no thread idly waiting for that operation to complete, and only **after** it has completed a thread will be given (usually by the `Thread Pool`) to continue running code on your CPU.

When you don't use `async-await` (or a different asynchronous paradigm like `Begin-End`) you would hold a thread **throughout** the operation, even in the IO parts of it, which is a waste of resources.

---

It's important to add that although most asynchronous examples regard IO operations, that's not always the case. In some cases it's reasonable to treat a CPU bound operation (where you do hold a thread throughout the whole operation) asynchronously.

Comment: But.. i thought that by default `await` is **not** using a threads, and that is useful for IO. And if i have some calculations to be done, i'm using `await Task.Run()` for async calculations in another thread.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko await itself doesn't do much. It only registers the next lines of code as a continuation. It means that you aren't using a thread **while** you're awaiting, but you do need one **after** you're done awaiting to execute the rest of the code.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Tash.Run will fire up a CPU bound operation that will itself hold a thread. But awaiting it will not. That's what I was referring to in my last part about asynchronous CPU bound operations.

Comment: But at which point a problem with thread appears (if not to talk about Task.Run()) with await? I have an await, it marks some files to be read (on the low level), then they signals that reading is done and Task returns the result. If there's nothing to do with a threads (like it is said in a first article), at which time some another thread jumps on the scene (like it is said in the second one)?

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko between getting a signal that an IO operation is done and marking the relevant task as completed with a result there **is** some code. Maybe not a lot but you need some thread to run it.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko here's the specific part describing it in Stephen's blog: "The task has captured the UI context, so it does not resume the async method directly on the thread pool thread. Instead, it queues the continuation of that method onto the UI context, and the UI thread will resume executing that method when it gets around to it."

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Sure. Any time.